# Errors when passing data via jquery ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have a pretty simple ajax request that I'm sending over to server in order to get some data and fill up my edit modal. But for some reason it keeps returning with error and I can't figure out why. I've debugged the server side, parameter comes in correctly and all data is properly found and returned, still an error though.

Here's my code so someone might see what am I missing here.

Request:

```
function EditNorm(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("GetNormViewModel")",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({id : id}),
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            FillFormForEditing(data.nvm);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Error On EditNorm function");
        }
    });
}
```

Server side:

```
public JsonResult GetNormViewModel(int id)
    {
        var nvm = new NormViewModel {Norm = db.Norms.Find(id), Materials = db.Materials.ToList()};

        return Json(new {nvm = nvm}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly: You are using a POST method on your javascript while your controller accepts a Get, add this to your action:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetNormViewModel(int id)
{
   return Json(new { ... });
}
```

Secondly: What is `db` is it LinqToSQL / Entity Framework context? If so, make sure no call to your data context is performed after the data is returned. (i.e. changed your action and simply return `return Json(new { nvm = "test" });` and `console.log/alert` to make sure you've got the result back. This will tells you that its your model that failed when it's returned due to some late binding.